# Incorporating DECODE() into SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm stuck in a bit of a rut here.  I want to incorporate a column for the city location using the DECODE() function to change the department number into the city name for a column named 'loc', kinda like this: decode(deptno,10,'NEW YORK')  .    But I'm not sure how to fit it in there without the code not running.  Everything I've tried so far has been unsuccessful.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
Create view emp_view_updt as Select e.empno, e.ename, e.job, d.deptno, d.loc from emp e inner join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Create view emp_view_updt as 
    Select e.empno, e.ename, e.job, d.deptno, 
       DECODE (d.loc, 10, 'NEW YORK', 
                          2, 'San Francisco', 
                          3, 'New Jersey', 
                          4, 'Seattle',
                          'Non domestic') as loc 
    from emp e inner join 
         dept d 
         on e.deptno = d.deptno;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `case` expression!  `decode()` is not only highly specific to Oracle, but Oracle has supported `case` for *decades*.

So:

```
create view emp_view_updt as
    select e.empno, e.ename, e.job, d.deptno,
           (case when deptno = 10 then 'NEW YORK' end) as loc
    from emp e inner join
         dept d
         on e.deptno = d.deptno;
```

You can repeat `when`/`then` clauses for other values.

Comment: CASE statements will generally perform better than DECODE

Comment: @Scott . . . Do you have any documentation for that?  I strongly prefer `CASE` expressions, but am not aware that they actually improve performance.

Comment: I want to get back to you on that. I'm sure I've seen at least two documented comparisons, but I might also try my own. It's inherently faster in some cases thanks to short circuit evaluation. As demonstrated with nvl vs coalese http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2010/02/one-more-coalesce-vs-nvl-example-to.html

Comment: @Scott . . . Ahh, I can see how short-circuiting would be a big performance gain.  I'm really surprised though by `nvl()` versus `coalesce()`.

Comment: There can be other unintended consequences too, such as one I inadvertantly demonstrated recently with nvl(:new.id, some_seq.nextval). Evaluating both expressions can be a drag.